# WYSIWYG Editor ideas SharePoint 2013 Site

Tags: 2013, javascript, html, html-editor

Are there are any WYSIWYG editors for SharePoint 2013 sites? I want the users who have little knowledge of web design to be able to dynamically edit the site content. If there isn't anything on SharePoint directly is there any good third party software that I can use, or and libraries that I can use to efficiently build my own editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using CKEditor as a WYSIWYG editor which works great for .Net applications. You can go through their samples and see if it matches in your case.

[CKEditor Samples For Ajax Application](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/saveajax.html)

Comment: I'm looking for more options than that. Such as allowing the users to add predefined widgets to the page like a search bar, forum post section and such. However if I have to build my own widgets in the end CKEditor seems useful.

Comment: Yes. You can add other widgets also to the same page.